# Numba: How to avoid <type 'reflected list' found for argument> warning?

Tags: python, numba

In a `numba` function, I was passing the arguments like this:

```
sets_one_step(idx,sets=[set1, set2], indexes=[sort_idx1, sort_idx2], probs=[P1, P2])
```

After running the code I got the following warning:

```
/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/core/ir_utils.py:2031: NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning: 
Encountered the use of a type that is scheduled for deprecation: type 'reflected list' found for argument 'sets' of function '__numba_parfor_gufunc_0x7f5ebfb88748'.
```

this particular error/warning may have originated from the following line inside the function:

```
for k in prange(len(sets)):
```

Here, `set1, set2` are numpy arrays (`integer` or `flaot32`). If this was only 2 sets, then I could make them individual arguments in function. However, I can have more than 2 such arrays for my application. I would like to know how to avoid this warning in future for my use case.

Comment: It seems your function argument *sets* and its values are not related to set types, and here they are just names of numpy arrays; So, using `sets=nb.typed.List([set1, set2])` could pass your problem as mentioned in [the aerobiomat answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68142289/13394817).

Answer (score 11):

Consider the following code:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def process_some_list(lst):
    return lst[0]
```

Passing a standard Python list produces the following output:

```
>>> process_some_list([1,2,3])
.../numba/core/ir_utils.py:2119: NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning: 
Encountered the use of a type that is scheduled for deprecation:
type 'reflected list' found for argument 'lst' of function 'process_some_list'.
For more information visit https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-reflection-for-list-and-set-types
[... more lines deleted ...]
1
```

The result is correct, but Numba says that `reflected list` is scheduled for deprecation. According to the [docs](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-reflection-for-list-and-set-types) you can use a [typed.List](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pysupported.html#feature-typed-list), as in this example:

```
>>> process_some_list(nb.typed.List([1,2,3]))
1
```

However, if you need a list of sets:

```
>>> lst = [{1, 2}, {3, 4}]
>>> process_some_list(nb.typed.List(lst))
```

You get the same deprecation message for Set:

```
.../numba/typed/typedlist.py:83: NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning: 
Encountered the use of a type that is scheduled for deprecation: type 'reflected set' found for argument 'item' of function 'impl_append.<locals>.impl'.
For more information visit https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-reflection-for-list-and-set-types
[... more lines deleted ...]
{1, 2}
```

The result is again correct, but the docs say `typed.Set` is not yet implemented, so you may need to live with the warnings. They only appear when the function is compiled, either during the first execution, or upon declaration when using signatures for the parameters and return type.

Comment: So basically as I understand from the mentioned docs, numba will soon stop doing its magic for plain python list objects (as they could not be optimized safely enough in in terms of mutability scenarios when interoperating with the standard cpython implementation), and will rather require user code to enter their list data as an encapsulated numba class `numba.typed.List`, which would avoid the cpython compatibility challenge.

Comment: I think you can alternatively use a numpy array container, but it [may seem possibly slower](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4355#issuecomment-519470930).